# How to clone() a element n times?

Tags: jquery, clone

I have a dynamic table that I want to attach `<col>` elements with jQuery.

I have this:

```
var tds = jQuery("tr > td").length; // count how many tds
jQuery("#colgroup-compare > col").clone() // clone
    .appendTo('#colgroup-compare'); // and append
```

Obviously this only appends 1 `<col>`, I want to append (n) numbers. How would I do this?

I have the length, I have the clone ability, now how do I combine it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a loop :

```
var $col = $("#colgroup-compare > col");
for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
    $col.clone().appendTo('#colgroup-compare');
}
```

You can't use `jQuery("#colgroup-compare > col").clone().appendTo('#colgroup-compare');` in your loop because that would append more cols at iterations > 0...

This can be optimized :

```
var $colgroup = $('#colgroup-compare'); // this saves the colgroup collection to avoid recomputing it later
var $col = $colgroup.children("col"); // this makes the clonable col(s) from the col children of $colgroup
for (var i=n; i-->0;){ // n times (from n-1 to 0)
    $colgroup.append($col.clone()); // append a clone of the col(s)
}
```

EDIT : to count the `th` in your first row, you may do this :

```
var n=$("tr").first().children('th').length;
```

(this avoid counting on more than one row)

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/mQEYu/)

Comment: Good point, but maybe more caching of the selectors' results.

Comment: @Tadeck Why not, but this isn't so important with a small n (document.getElementById is fast) and this would make the code less readable. But I agree this could be done.

Comment: @Tadeck I made a new version : do you like it better ?

Comment: Thanks, but could you expand on that answer for me? I am new to javascript (and stackoverflow, damn that answer came fast) and this got complicated quickly. I did some quick research and each() seems to be the jQuery equivalent.

Edit: It seems like you start counting the col elements while I need to count the td element first so I can append the col after!?

Comment: I commented the second one and added a demonstration (link at the bottom).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed help and patience, it now works!<br>

Comment: Should you not save the clone in a variable and then append in the loop?

Comment: @SazzadTusharKhan No, because an element can't be at two places at the same time. When you append it, you remove it from its other location.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want deep clones, then you can avoid the manual iteration by passing the [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.outerHTML) of the element to an arrays [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method resulting in an HTMLString corresponding to `n` number of elements as shown below:

```
var elementString = new Array(++n).join($(selector).get(0).outerHTML)
```

which you can append to any element you wish.

---

In your case you can do:

```
var n= $("tr > td").length,
$colgroup = $("#colgroup-compare");
$colgroup.append(new Array(++n).join($colgroup.find("col").get(0).outerHTML));
```